# Switch statement error

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I am running into error after error with this program.  At this point, things seem to be in order for the most part and I can compile without errors, however when I run the program and I'm asked to enter a letter grade, entering any letter grade will give me this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMisMatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at GPA.main(GPA.java:28)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.. Excuse my noobness, I am brand new to Java (in my 3rd day of programming) but very determined.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class GPA

```
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of classes: ");
    int numberClasses = kbReader.nextInt();

    int i;
    int totalCreditForGPA = 0;
    int totalCreditHours = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < numberClasses; i++)
      {

      System.out.print("Enter letter grade of class: ");
      int letterGrade = kbReader.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter credit hour of class: ");
      int creditHour = kbReader.nextInt();

    switch (letterGrade)
        {
       case 'A':
       case 'a': totalCreditForGPA = (int) totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 4);
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'B':
      case 'b':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 3);
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'C':
      case 'c':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 2);
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'D':
      case 'd':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 1);
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'F':
      case 'f':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 0);
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      default:
             System.out.println("Invalid letter grade.");
        }
      }
    int GPA = totalCreditForGPA;
    System.out.println("Your GPA is " + GPA);
   }
}
```

Comment: You're reading an integer but comparing it with a character?

Comment: I don't know what you mean Bergi, could you explain in more detail?  Like I said I'm brand new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char letterGrade =(char) kbReader.next().toCharArray()[0];
```

i think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't figure how to write that line out but that's what I was lookin for.

Comment: next() method returns a string and string can be converted to char array and `[0]` used to get first element from array.

Comment: hey brother i recommend you read about java syntax and programming basics then start to code because its not wise to ask everything when you don't know what they mean. We can provide solutions but to learn you gotta study boy!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare letterGrade you're declaring it as an int and reading an int

```
int letterGrade = kbReader.nextInt();
```

But then in your switch you use a char

```
`case 'A':
```

Should be `case 1:` or any other int.

Comment: I see, for some reason I got char mixed up with int.

Comment: In this case, how should I format things?  

System.out.print("Enter letter grade of class: ");
   String letterGrade = kbReader.nextLine();
   char ch = letterGrade.charAt(0);

Would this suffice? I am getting more errors when I try to use that, but that's the only way I know how to use Char

Comment: Why not to just use a String? To use Scanner I think you need to use kbReader.next(); then pass the result to a char[] with toCharArray(); and finally test against char[0]. edit: Oh, but charAt() should work as well. What error are you getting?